# Access 2007: Find value in another table and display list in popup

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

all - First-time question asker here, although I have found many excellent solutions here in the past. I didn't see anything that I could use or adapt for my current dilemma, though.

I would like to create a macro that will use a field in one table to find the same value in another table and display a list of information for that value from the other table in a popup menu. VBA is fine, although I would prefer a method that uses the macro builder in Access.

Here is example data from the two tables:

```
Table1 - Transaction Data
Field1       Field2       Field3       Field4...
AAM          12345678E    1024.34      01/01/15

Table2 - Pricing Data
Field1       Field2       Field3      Field4      Field5...
12345678E    08/13/10     1000.00     1000.10     997.42    
12345678E    09/30/11     1100.00     1110.00     995.23
12345678E    01/01/15     975.14      1024.34     1030.42
12345678F    05/20/15     800.12      800.74      801.24
12345678F    06/15/15     794.56      797.00      799.34
12345678G    03/06/13     12.2331     14.92       18.245
```

I want to be able to run the macro on the value in Table1/Field2 that pops up a display of all matches from Table2/Field1 with data from T2/F2+

The popup should look like this:

```
Field1       Field2       Field3     Field4...
08/13/10     1000.00     1000.10     997.42    
09/30/11     1100.00     1110.00     995.23
01/01/15     975.14      1024.34     1030.42
```

The field names should pick up the headers from the other table. It would be nice if the title box of the popup contained the lookup value (T1/F2) but not necessary.

Note: I am not looking to autopopulate a field in T1, just show a list of values so I can see at a glance how to classify the value in T1/F3.

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially a simple query. Save the below as a stored query object.

```
SELECT * FROM Table2
INNER JOIN Table1.Field1 = Table.Field2
```

Then, create a continuous form or datasheet whose recordsource is the above query (i.e., open saved query and create the multiple item form while query is opened).

Finally, have the form opened in a button OnClick() or other trigger event by adding the [Open Form](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb177336(v=office.12).aspx) command in the event's embedded macro.

Comment: Had to look up continuous forms... great discussion here:
http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=1949620

Pretty sure your solution will work for me - will mark it as solution after I do some testing. THANKS!!

Comment: In AC2007, on Ribbon, under [Create tab](http://accessdatabasetutorial.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/191/files/2011/01/access_ribbonbars.jpg), in Forms section there is a Multiple Item icon (for continuous forms) and More Forms with dropdown arrow (for datasheet forms).